# Json deserialization with multiple json file for Multiplicity relationship

Tags: c#, json, oop, json-deserialization, software-design

I have an object model as below, some of the objects have zero or more relationships

```
public class Foo
{
 public string Id
 public string Name
}

public class Bar
{
 public string Id
 public Foo Foo
 public DateTime At
}

public class Baz
{
 public string Id
 public DateTime At
 public List<Bar> Bars
}

public class Qux
{
 public string Id
 public string Name
 public List<Baz> Baz
}
```

I need to deserialize the following 4 json files.

Foo.json

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "AAA"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "BBB"
  }
]
```

Bar.json

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "FooId": "1",
    "BazId": "1",
    "At": "2022-01-01T10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "FooId": "2",
    "BazId": "1",
    "At": "2022-01-02T10:00:00"
  }
]
```

Baz.json

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Quxd": "1",
    "At": "2022-01-01T10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "QuxId": "1",
    "At": "2022-01-02T10:00:00"
  }
]
```

Qux.Json

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "CCC"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "DDD"
  }
]
```

I know it is a badly designed JSON file and I cannot change that and that is my challenge to resolve it without changing the json.

I was able to solve the issue, by creating another 4 sets of objects for each JSON and deserializing them individually, after that, I will have a loop for object4 to map all other objects.

But I feel it is not that efficient.

Please let me know if you have any other ideas so that I can solve this in a much better way.

Thanks

Comment: Your Object2, Object3 and Object4 classes don't fit Json2, Json3 and Json4. Can you post the real code or tell us what is correct  json or class?

Comment: @Serge Thanks for checking this, I have updated the question, hope it make sense now

Comment: And what is the problem?  You have 4 json files, do you want to merge them in one or what?

Comment: Yes, I think If I can merge them into one file, then deserialize them to my entity model, it would be quicker. The approach that I have taken now is, to deserialize each JSON separately with a different object model and then map them to my entity model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is badly formatted json, so please ignore

Answer (score 0):

I think another way could be to [merge json files](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) and then just deserialise them to classes:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'Enabled': false,
  'Roles': [ 'User' ]
}");
JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'Enabled': true,
  'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
}");

o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    // union array values together to avoid duplicates
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
});
```

When you have merged arrays, then you can use this beautiful tool to create model classes by json file. [Converting json to C#](https://json2csharp.com)

Comment: Who told you that all json files item are in the same order? and where is the class are you going to use for the merged files?

Comment: For your first question: OP can say whether it is eligible this approach to him. For the second question: you can use this beautiful tool to create model classes by json file. [Converting json to C#](https://json2csharp.com)

Comment: @StepUp Thank you for your answer, but json merged doesn't help this situation as they are different data set. 
Again I know this is a badly design json. I am writing up for a technical test and this is my challange to sort it out.

Comment: @Ash yeah, merging is for for different data set. ok. Feel free to upvote if you find that my reply was helpful :) [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)